# How to sendMessage both in interfaceController and in Glance?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2, watchconnectivity

I was able to implement a sendMessage method in my `interfacecontroller` that calls out to the iPhone and receives the latest data back to update my Watch app's UI.  It works well.  However, the same strategy:  `activiating session` and `sendMessage` in my `GlanceController` does not get the data back.  Looking around online my understanding is that my watch app is probably itercepting the message.

Is there a work around for this so that I can get the same functionality in my `Glancecontroller`?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `[[WCSession defaultSession] reachable]` is NO in your glance controller, which seems to be a pretty widely reported issue with watchOS 2. WCSession's sendMessage only works when `reachable` is YES.
Before using sendMessage you should always check if `reachable` is YES otherwise you are likely to get a "not reachable" error returned.

Comment: Which brings up another frustrating issue with Watch programming, I cannot debug on my device..Xcode stops "running" after it attaches so that I can't test for such things.  Thanks for your input though, I've also tried sending applicationContext which doesn't require rechability so I don't think that's it.

Comment: If applicationContext doesn't work either then your problem sounds bug report worthy :) if you do file one report back here with the radar number so the apple engineers can easily track it down!